# Как открыть приложение и перейти по заданому url в WebView?

Tags: javascript, java, cordova

Я использую cordova.
Не могу понять как мне с помощью ссылки запустить приложение и перейти на нужный URL адрес в WebView.
Я скачал плагин: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-customurlscheme

Приложение открывается по ссылки, но не переходит в WebView. То есть просто открылось и всё. А надо, чтобы переходило по указанной ссылке.

Сейчас использую ссылки такого вида: `MYAPP.https://site.ru/`
вначале ставлю идентификатор приложения MYAPP, а потом через точку пишу ссылку. Идентификатор получается срабатывает и открывает приложение, а по ссылки не переходит. Как правильно написать, чтобы совершался переход по ссылке?

Answer (score -1):

Разобрался. Необходимо было обрабатывать ссылки, отрезая от них лишнее.

Такой код помог:

```
      handleOpenURL = OpenPush;
      function OpenPush (url) {
      var strValue = url;
      strValue = strValue.replace('auspapp://','');
      window.location = strValue;
      }
```

`auspapp://` - это то что надо было отрезать.